# libvirt-go DomainEventLifecycleRegister "could not initialize domain event timer"

Tags: qemu, libvirt, virsh

I have installed `libvirt-dev`, compiled and run that code on a Ubuntu box:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go"
)

func main() {
    conn, _ := libvirt.NewConnect("qemu:///system")
    defer conn.Close()

    cb := func(c *libvirt.Connect, d *libvirt.Domain, event *libvirt.DomainEventLifecycle) {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Event %d", event.Event))
    }

    _, err := conn.DomainEventLifecycleRegister(nil, cb)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("cannot register libvirt domain event: %s", err))
   }
}
```

And got: `cannot register libvirt domain event: virError(Code=1, Domain=0, Message='internal error: could not initialize domain event timer')`

I'm using [libvirt-go](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go) while digital ocean [go-libvirt](https://github.com/digitalocean/go-libvirt) `LifecycleEvents` just works fine...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not registered any event loop implementation.

The easy way is to call `EventRegisterDefaultImpl` before opening a libvirt connection, and then spawn a goroutine that runs  `EventRunDefaultImpl` in an infinite loop

The harder way is to provide your own custom event loop implementation using `EventRegisterImpl`

Comment: Thank you very much.